# jquery bind unbind

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a site where dynamically load page inside the conatiner. I have a menu of navigation like this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <p align="left" id="home" class="titolo_menu">home</p>
    <p align="left" id="azienda" class="titolo_menu azienda"><br>azienda</p>
    <p align="left" id="staff" class="titolo_sotto_menu azienda">staff</p>
    <p align="left" id="risorseumane" class="titolo_sotto_menu azienda">risorse umane</p>
</div>
```

And into my jQuery I have added this line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.titolo_menu').bind('click',function(){
            $('.titolo_menu').unbind('click');
             //more code...
     });
  });
```

I want when a user click on a p with class "titolo_menu" disable the event click but doesn't work, I can click more and more time. How can I solve it?

Comment: Your code works for me? http://jsfiddle.net/pimlinders/j8cDC/

Comment: `align` attribute is deprecated, use `<ul>` + `<li>` inside a `<nav>` element for navigation, and use `<a>`'s for links. Then reproduce your problem on a fiddle so it's easier to help you ^^

Comment: @undefined because after I have to enable again the click event

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, bind/unbind is deprecated in favor of the on/off methods.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have tried with on e off instead of bind and unbind.. doesn't work too

Comment: *"because after I have to enable again the click event"* and where is that code? The code given does not produce the problem you are describing.

Comment: In my site I can click always into that p. The code where I enable the click event isn't important because is commented now the problem is to unbind or disable the event click

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri if you tell us about your goal [show some content, cycle thru tabs...], it would be easier to help you, because clicking on a `<p>` seems a very *odd* interaction.

Comment: the goal is now to disbale click event and enable after may function but now I can't disable it, I don't know why this code doesn't work. I think the problem is that I load many page dynamically and something enable again my click event, document.ready? I don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I couldn't figure out what you really want in your application, consider using `data-*` attributes to same some state inside DOM itself, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.titolo_menu').on('click',function(){

        // let's create a reference for current element
        $p = $(this);

        // if clicked element had data-disabled attribute set, return
        if($p.data('disabled'))
            return;

        // disable element;
        $p.data('disabled', true);

        // do your stuff here, e.g.
        $.get('dapage.html', function(data){

            // do your stuff on data retrieving
            $(something).html(data);

            // re-enable element
            $p.data('disabled', false);

        });

   });
});
```

This way you can have control over events, without messing with unbinding.

Comment: This work I have data attributes and now I can disable and enable easily my DOM elements

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var return_flag = true;
    $('.titolo_menu').bind('click',function(){
        if(return_flag){
             //more code...
        }
    return_flag = false;
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change class name

```
$('.titolo_menu').bind('click',function(){
           $(this).removeClass('.titolo_menu');
             //more code...
     });
```

Or if you want to disable all elements:

```
$('.titolo_menu').bind('click',function(){
            $('.titolo_menu').removeClass('.titolo_menu');
             //more code...
     });
```

Doesn't work if you use 'live' insted of 'bind'

//Edit
Sorry it won't work. 
Just use live:

```
$('.titolo_menu').live('click', function(){
  $('.titolo_menu').removeClass('.titolo_menu');
});
```

But if you just want to prevent multiple click whie page is loading just use

```
.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: It's actually quite the opposite, it will only work IF you use .live instead of .bind.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd like to advice you to use an unsorted list when creating menu's and use `<a>` tags to link the pages.

Example:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="home" class="titolo_menu"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
    <li id="azienda" class="titolo_menu azienda"><a href="#azienda">azienda</a></li>
    <li id="staff" class="titolo_sotto_menu azienda"><a href="#staff">staff</a></li>
    <li id="risorseumane" class="titolo_sotto_menu azienda"><a href="#risorseumane">risorse umane</a></li>
</ul>
```

In jQuery you could then do something like this:

```
$(function() {

    $("#menu a").click(function(e) {
        var clickedElement = $(this);
        var clickedElementText = clickedElement.text();

        // Check if current link is not yet active
        if (!$(clickedElement).hasClass("active")) {

            if ($(".active").length > 0) {
                // Deactivate current active link
                var active = $(".active ");
                var activeText = $(active).text();

                $(".active").replaceWith("<a href = '#" + active.parent().attr("id") + "' > " + activeText + " </a>");
            }
            // Change the clicked link to be activated
            $(clickedElement).replaceWith("<span class='active'>" + clickedElementText + "</span>");

            // Load your page or whatever here :)

            // Prevent normal link behavior
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't use tag a because I have to do particular thing and a link isn't the right solution, I know well html and I know that is better but not in this case sorry

Comment: Could you explain why it isn't a correct solution. My solution should work if you change them to `<p>` tags.

Comment: because I want that when a use go over doens't go lo a link there a re case where isn't clickable like if you are in the same page doesn't have to refresh the page and is more comfortable to use p instead f tag a

Comment: Still not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. Either way, I hope someone is able to answer your question.

Comment: already answer, is a very complex layout and logic is the best way for many reason believe me